# .sh and .php file not working on crontab - updated

Tags: scripts, php, cron, paths, sh

I am using Cloud9 Server. I have an .sh file that works fine when I open it on terminal, however, when I add a crontab task in crontab -e to open this file, it does not work well.

My .sh file creates a backup of my website and send this to a path that I chose.

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/php remote.phar --action=backup --host=http://admiravelidiota-rodmsantos.c9users.io --secret=MySecretKey --download --dlmode=http --dlpath= "/home/ubuntu/workspace/" 

/bin/echo "Executed"
```

I made this file to be "executed" by a php file of the kind:

```
<?php
    $contents = file_get_contents('/home/ubuntu/workspace/teste.sh');
    echo shell_exec($contents);
?>
```

Then, I added this php file to be executed on crontab to be performed every 5 minutes such as:

```
*/5 * * * * lynx http://gustavo-gustavomoty.c9users.io/php.php
```

I have already tried crontab executing the .sh file directly, it did not work, that is why I am trying by the .php file but still not working.

Comment: Use `/usr/bin/php` instead of `php` and then check..

Comment: What are the permissions of said file?

Comment: it didn't work switching from `php` to `/usr/bin/php`.

Comment: And you want to use `./teste.sh` only when your shell script is located in the current directory. Remove the trailing dot.

Comment: Still not working.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your crontab entry may be wrong. The 6th field in the entry should be the username who runs the process not the shell that runs the script. So assuming that you dont have a user called "sh", replace the entry with your username.

eg (assuming that you want the command to run as user "bob"):

```
*/5 * * * * bob /home/ubuntu/workspace/teste.sh
```

(edited to include grooveplex's comment)

Comment: And you want to use `./teste.sh` only when your shell script is located in the current directory. Remove the trailing dot.

Comment: Still not working.

Comment: Can you paste your full crontab?

Comment: My .sh file creates a backup of my website and send this to a path that I chose.

`#!/bin/bash`
    
`/usr/bin/php -f remote.phar --action=backup --host=http://admiravelidiota-rodmsantos.c9users.io --secret=MySecretKey --download --dlmode=http --dlpath= "/home/ubuntu/workspace/"`
    
`echo "Executed"`

My full crontab -e is:


`*/2 * * * * gustavo /home/ubuntu/workspace/teste.sh`

Comment: Do I have to use sudo crontab -e instead?

Comment: Sorry, I had assumed that you had added the line to `/etc/crontab`, rather than use `crontab -e`, so your original form (in my view) was correct

Comment: The file that you want to execute is in the directory /home/ubuntu, but your username is gustavo, I assume that you are looking to run the script from a different home directory? Can you paste the output of `ls -l /home/ubuntu/workspace/teste.sh`

Comment: the output was: `-rwxr-xr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu 279 Aug 15 20:20 /home/ubuntu/workspace/teste.sh*`

Comment: Sorry, just rereading, if you are using crontab -e, can you use the following line `*/5 * * * * /home/ubuntu/workspace/teste.sh`, also change the last line of the script to `echo $? "Executed"`?

Comment: Still not working. :/